# How does one use the Johansen cointegration test in a linear time series model?

Tags: time-series, time

How does one use the Johansen cointegration test in a linear time series model?

Should I only use normalized coeffients for interpretation? Or, once I know that the variables are cointegrated, do I simply regress the variables and consider it the long-run relationship?

Answer (score 1):

no, you should use your original variables, no truncating, normalizing or whatever. And remember that you need Johansen only in case of more than one independent variable.